# add regex as parameter in a Cypress cucumber step definition

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I want to check this complete line with Cypress but the time mentioned can vary. Can I use a regex for this and how do i do this? Thanks

`Then I verify the AL notification list contains unread item "some text 03:39 some more text"`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you hide the regex implementation inside the step code, to avoid ugly reports.

`Then I verify the AL notification list contains unread item "some text 99:99 some more text"`

```js
Then('I verify the AL notification list contains unread item {string}', (item) => {
  const re = new RegExp(item.replace('99:99', '\d{2}:\d{2}'))
  cy.get(select).invoke('text').should('match', re)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your feature file**:

```
Then I verify the AL notification list contains unread item ".*(\d{2}:\d{2}).*"
```

Can try the regex *".*(\d{2}:\d{2}).*"* to match with your text *"some text 03:39 some more text*" here: https://regexr.com/7esif

**In your step definition**:

```
Then('I verify the AL notification list contains unread item {string}', (regexString) => {
   const regexSearch = new RegExp(regexString, "g"); // convert string to regex by using RegExp object constructor 
   cy.get('div or id ').invoke('text').should('match', regexSearch); // get element text then match with regex using match(RegExp) 
})
```

**Explanation**

1. pass regex as parameter in your feature file
2. convert string to regex by using RegExp object constructor : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
3. get element text then match with regex using "match(RegExp)" https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai